# How to get the count of entries of specified element in List<>()?

Tags: c#, list

Are there more productively methods to do it?

```
int count = list.FindAll(c => c.Equals(specifiedElement));
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Count` method instead of `FindAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use linq's [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method:

```
var count = list.Count(c => c.Equals(specifiedElement));
```

Comment: The only potential issue I see is that it might be better to use `object.Equals(c, specifiedElement)` for safety against nulls. I doubt that's the reason for the downvote - I imagine whoever downvoted doesn't feel the question is worth answering.